# Creating custom Cordova plugin for NfcV Tags

Tags: javascript, java, cordova, cordova-plugins

I need to read the Data off NfcV (ISO 15693) Tags, I already tried the Phonegap-Nfc Plugin from Chariotsolution, but it seems this plugin can only read the TagId and Type off NfcV tags, so i decided i could create my own custom plugin, I first foud the echo Hello World Plugin tutorial which worked fine and without problems, so I looked for Java NfcV reader and found this [Java NfcV Reader](https://code.google.com/p/nfcutils/source/browse/org/android/nfc/tech/ReadNfcV.java?r=71e8373bc57e64a1fc961b7990fe00fcf138ba8d).

From what I understood so far is, that I need to call the cordova.exec function and extend my Java class from CordovaPlugin, which is working.

I don't know Java since I am a Webdeveloper, which makes it a little hard for me.

This actually looks pretty good but i tried to implement it in the way of the Hello World echo example which didnt work out as planned.

I have now a plugin folder with

Hello.java

```
    package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

    import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
    import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;


    /**
     * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
     */
    public class Hello extends CordovaPlugin
    {
        @Override
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
            if (action.equals("hello")) {
                String message = args.getString(0);
                this.hello(message, callbackContext);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void hello(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
            if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
                callbackContext.success(message);
            } else {
                callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
            }
        }
    }
```

ReadNfcV.java from the link above

```
    package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

    import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
    import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;

    import android.nfc.Tag;
    import android.nfc.TagLostException;
    import android.nfc.tech.NfcV;
    import android.nfc.tech.TagTechnology;
    //import android.os.Parcelable;
    import android.util.Log;

    /**
        * @author uhahn
        *
        */
    public class ReadNfcV extends CordovaPlugin implements TagTechnology {
            protected NfcV mynfcv;
    //      protected Tag mytag; // can be retrieved through mynfcv
    
            private final String TAG=this.getClass().getName();
            protected final int maxtries=3;
    
            protected boolean isTainted=true; // Tag info already read?
            protected byte[] mysysinfo=null;        // NfcV SystemInformation - or generated
            protected byte[] myuserdata=null;       // buffer user content
            protected boolean[] blocktainted;       // true when block is to be uploaded to tag
            protected byte[] blocklocked;           // 0 means writable
    
            protected byte afi=0;
            public byte nBlocks=0;
            public byte blocksize=0;
            public byte[] Id;
            public byte[] UID; // becomes valid when a real tag is contacted
            public byte DSFID = -1;
            public int maxtrans=0; // tag dependent max transceive length
            public byte lastErrorFlags=-1; // re-set by each transceive
            public byte lastErrorCode=-1; // re-set by each transceive
            public byte manuByte=0;
    
            public static final byte BYTE_IDSTART=(byte)0xe0;
            public static final byte MANU_TAGSYS=0x04;
            public static final HashMap<Byte,String> manuMap = new HashMap<Byte, String>();
    
            static{
                    manuMap.put(MANU_TAGSYS, "TagSys");
            }
    
            /**
             * read new NfcV Tag from NFC device
             */
            public ReadNfcV(Tag t) {
                    UID = t.getId(); // sysinfo holds the UID in lsb order -  Id will be filled lateron from sysinfo!
    //              Log.d(TAG,"getId: "+toHex(t.getId()));
                    mynfcv=NfcV.get(t);
                    try {
                            mynfcv.connect();
                            mysysinfo=getSystemInformation(); 
                            // explore Nfcv properties..
                            //initfields(); // done by getSys..

                            maxtrans=mynfcv.getMaxTransceiveLength();
                            DSFID=mynfcv.getDsfId();
                            Log.d(TAG,nBlocks + " x " + blocksize + " bytes");
                            blocklocked=new byte[nBlocks]; // init the lock shadow
                            getMultiSecStatus(0, nBlocks);  // and fill from tag
                    
                            blocktainted=new boolean[nBlocks];
                            taintblock(0,nBlocks);
                    
    //                      Log.d(TAG,"maxtrans "+maxtrans);
                            // init space for userdata ?
                            myuserdata= new byte[nBlocks*blocksize]; 
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            lastErrorFlags=-1;
                            Log.d(TAG, "MyNfcV failed: "+e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
    
            /**
             * recreate NfcV Tag from log
             * @param sysinfo: the logged system info only
             */
            public ReadNfcV(String sysinfo){
                    int startat=0;
                    sysinfo.toLowerCase(); // ignore case
                    if(sysinfo.startsWith("0x")){ // lets believe in HEX
                            startat=2;
                    }
                    mysysinfo=hexStringToByteArray(sysinfo.substring(startat));
                    initfields();
                    // init space for userdata TODO limit size?
                    //myuserdata= new byte[nBlocks*blocksize]; 
                    isTainted=false; 
    // TODO fake Tag?               mytag = Tag.CREATOR.createFromParcel(???);
            }

            /**
             * recreate NfcV Tag from log
             * @param sysinfo: the logged system info
             * @param userdata: the logged userdata
             */
            public ReadNfcV(String sysinfo, String userdata){
                    this(sysinfo);
                    // TODO fake userdata
                    int startat=0;
                    userdata.toLowerCase(); // ignore case
                    if(userdata.startsWith("0x")){ // lets believe in HEX
                            startat=2;
                    }
                    myuserdata=hexStringToByteArray(userdata.substring(startat));
            }
    
            /**
             * parse system information byte array into attributes
             * with respect to the flags found
             * DSFID
             * AFI
             * memsize values (block count and length)
             */
            private void initfields(){
                    byte[] read=mysysinfo;
                    if((null!=read)&&(12<read.length)&&(0==read[0])){// no error
                            char flags=(char)read[1]; //s.charAt(1);

                            //      String s=new String(read);
                            //s.substring(2, 9).compareTo(Id.toString())  // the same?
                            //set the Id from mysysinfo
                            int pos=2;
                            boolean forwardId=false; // the Id field is in lsb order
                            if(BYTE_IDSTART==read[pos]){
                                    forwardId=true;
                                    manuByte=read[pos+1];
                            }else if(BYTE_IDSTART==read[pos+7]){
                                    manuByte=read[pos+6];
                                    forwardId=false;
                            }else
                                    Log.e(TAG,"Id start byte not found where expected");
                            if(null==Id){ // dont overwrite, if given
                                    Id=new byte[8];
                                    for(int i=0;i<8;i++) 
                                            // TODO decide if Id to be reversed (Zebra needs msb order, that is Id[7] changes between tags)
                                            Id[i]=(forwardId? read[pos+i] : read[pos + 7 - i]); //reverse?!
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Id from sysinfo (reversed): "+toHex(Id));
                            }
                    
                            pos=10; // start after flags, Infoflags and Id TODO: change if transceive should eat up the error byte 
                            if(0<(flags&0x1)){ // DSFID valid
                                    pos++; // already implemented 
                            }
                            if(0<(flags&0x2)){ // AFI valid
                                    afi=(byte)read[pos++];//s.charAt(pos++);
                            }
                            if(0<(flags&0x4)){ // memsize valid
                                    nBlocks=(byte)(read[pos++]+1);//(s.charAt(pos++)+1);
                                    blocksize=(byte)(read[pos++]+1); //((s.charAt(pos++)&0x1f)+1);
                            }       
                    }
            }
    
            /**
             * @return the stored afi byte
             */
            public byte getAFI(){
                    if(isTainted){ // system info not read yet
                            getSystemInformation(); // fill in the fields
                    }
                    return afi;
            }
    
            public byte getDsfId(){
    //              return mynfcv.getDsfId(); // avoid re-reading
                    return DSFID;
            }
    
            public int getblocksize(){
                    return (int)blocksize;
            }
    
            public int getnBlocks(){
                    return (int)nBlocks;
            }
    
            public byte[] getSystemInformation(){
                    if(isTainted){ // dont reread 
                            mysysinfo=transceive((byte)0x2b);
                            isTainted=false; // remember: we have read it and found it valid
                            if(0==lastErrorFlags){// no error
                                    isTainted=false; // remember: we have read it and found it valid
                                    initfields(); // analyze 
                            }}
                    return mysysinfo;
            }
    
            /**
             * overload method transceive
             * @return resulting array (or error?)
             */
            protected byte[] transceive(byte cmd){
                    return transceive(cmd, -1, -1, null);
            }

            protected byte[] transceive(byte cmd, int m){
                    return transceive(cmd, m, -1, null);
            }
    
            protected byte[] transceive(byte cmd, int m ,int n){
                    return transceive(cmd, m, n, null);
            }
    
            /**
             * prepare and run the command according to NfcV specification
             * @param cmd command byte
             * @param m command length
             * @param n 
             * @param in input data
             * @return
             */
            protected byte[] transceive(byte cmd,int m, int n, byte[] in){
                            byte[] command;
                            byte[] res="transceive failed message".getBytes();
            
                    ByteArrayBuffer bab = new ByteArrayBuffer(128);
                    // flags: bit x=adressed, 
                    bab.append(0x00);
                    bab.append(cmd); // cmd byte
                    // 8 byte UID - or unaddressed
            //      bab.append(mytag.getId(), 0, 8);
                    // block Nr
                    if(-1!=m)bab.append(m);
                    if(-1!=n)bab.append(n);
                    if(null!=in)bab.append(in, 0, in.length);
            
                    command=bab.toByteArray();
                    Log.d(TAG,"transceive cmd: "+toHex(command));
    //              Log.d(TAG,"transceive cmd length: "+command.length);
            
                    // TODO background!
                    try {
                            if(!mynfcv.isConnected()) return res;
                            for(int t=maxtries;t>0;t++){ // retry reading
                                    res=mynfcv.transceive(command);
                                    if(0==res[0]) break;
                            }
                    } 
                    catch (TagLostException e){ //TODO roll back user action
                            Log.e(TAG, "Tag lost "+e.getMessage());
                            try {
                                    mynfcv.close();
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            return e.getMessage().getBytes();               
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "transceive IOEx: "+e.getMessage()+toHex(res));
            //              e.printStackTrace();
                            return e.getMessage().getBytes();
                    }
                    finally{
                            Log.d(TAG,"getResponseFlags: "+mynfcv.getResponseFlags()); 
                            lastErrorFlags=res[0];
                            Log.d(TAG,"Flagbyte: "+String.format("%2x", lastErrorFlags));
                            if(0!=lastErrorFlags){
                                    lastErrorCode=res[1];
                                    Log.d(TAG,"ErrorCodebyte: "+String.format("%2x", lastErrorCode));
                            }
                    }

                    if(0==mynfcv.getResponseFlags())
                            return (res);
                    else
    //                      return new String("response Flags not 0").getBytes();
                            return res;
            }

    
            public void taintblock(int i, int n){
                    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                            setblocktaint(j,true);
            }

            public void taintblock(int i){
                    setblocktaint(i,true);
            }
    
            protected void setblocktaint(int i, boolean b){
                    blocktainted[i]=b;
            }
    
    
            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.nfc.tech.TagTechnology#getTag()
             * 
             */
            @Override
            public Tag getTag() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //return mytag;
                    return mynfcv.getTag();
            }
    
            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.nfc.tech.TagTechnology#close()
             */
            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                    try {
                            mynfcv.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Log.d(TAG, "close failed: "+e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.nfc.tech.TagTechnology#connect()
             */
            @Override
            public void connect() throws IOException {
                    try {
                            mynfcv.connect();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            lastErrorFlags=-1; // TODO discriminate error states
                            Log.d(TAG,"connect failed: "+e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see android.nfc.tech.TagTechnology#isConnected()
             */
            @Override
            public boolean isConnected() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //              mynfcv.getDsfId();
                    return mynfcv.isConnected(); // better?
            }

            public byte[] readSingleBlock(int i){
                    byte[] read=transceive((byte)0x20,i);
            
                    setblocktaint(i,false); // remember we read this block
                    if(0!=lastErrorFlags)return read; // TODO not so ignorant..
            
                    byte[] res=new byte[read.length-1]; // drop the (0) flag byte TODO: in transceive?
                    for (int l = 0; l < read.length-1; l++) {
                            res[l]=read[l+1];
                            myuserdata[i*blocksize+l]=res[l]; // sort block into our buffer
                    }
            
                    return res;
            
            }

            /**
             * 
             * @param i starting block number
             * @param j block count
             * @return block content concatenated 
             */
            public byte[] readMultipleBlocks(int i,int j){
                    if(0==blocksize){
                            Log.e(TAG,"readMult w/o initfields?");
                            getSystemInformation(); // system info was not read yet
                    }

                    byte[] read = transceive((byte)0x23,i,j);
                    if(0!=read[0])return read; // error flag set: TODO  left as exercise..

                    byte[] res=new byte[read.length-1]; // drop the (0) flag byte
                    for (int l = 0; l < read.length-1; l++) {
                            res[l]=read[l+1];
                            myuserdata[i*blocksize+l]=res[l]; // sort block into our buffer
                    }
            
                    if(res.length<j*blocksize) return read; // da fehlt was
                    for (int k = i; k < j; k++) { // all blocks we read
                            setblocktaint(k, false); // untaint blocks we read
    // @TODO reverting block order should be done on demand - or under user control (done again in DDMData)
    //              reverse(res,k*blocksize,blocksize); // swap string positions
                    }
                    return res;
            }
    
            public byte[] getMultiSecStatus(int i,int n){
                    byte[] read = transceive((byte)0x2c,i,n-1);
                    Log.d(TAG,"secstatus "+toHex(read));
                    if(0!=read[0])return read;
                    int startat=1; // TODO transceive will skip the error field soon
            
                    for(int j=0;j<nBlocks;j++)
                            blocklocked[j]=read[startat+i+j];

                    return read;
            }
    
    

            /**
             * move anywhere to utils
             * @param s
             * @return
             */
    
        public static String toHex(byte[] in){
            String text=String.format("0x");
            for (byte  element : in) {
                            text=text.concat(String.format("%02x", element));
                    }
            return text;
        }

    
            public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
                int len = s.length();
                byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
                    data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                                         + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
                }
                return data;
            }
    }
```

my hello.js file

```
        var hello = {
        world: function(str, callback) {
            cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
                callback('Nothing to hello.');
            }, "Hello", "hello", [str]);
        }
    }

    var ReadNfcV = {
        read: function (str, callback) {
            cordova.exec(callback, function (err) {
                callback('Nothing to hello.');
            }, "Hello", "hello", [str]);
        }
    }

    module.exports = hello;
    module.exports = ReadNfcV;
```

and my plugin.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <plugin xmlns="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/plugins/1.0"
          id="org.apache.cordova.plugin"
          version="0.1.0">


      <js-module src="hello.js" name="hello">
          <clobbers target="hello" />
      </js-module>

      <!-- Android -->
      <platform name="android">
          <source-file src="Hello.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/plugin" />
          <source-file src="ReadNfcV.java" target-dir="src/org/apache/cordova/plugin" />

          <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
              <feature name="Hello" >
                  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.Hello"/>
              </feature>
          </config-file>
      </platform>
  </plugin>
```

I was able to deploy the app so I can test a bit, My problem is that I dont really understand how i can call the ReadNfc class from the ReadNfcV.java file from within my app via javascript. I just did the same as in the Tutorial but now the hello.World function is not a function anymore so i guess i did smth wrong in my hello.js file. I would really appreciate it if someone could help and explain me how i can call my java class via javascript and then return the result from the java class back to my javascript. I looked 2 Days for an already existing plugin but didnt find anything on that subject but the phonegap-nfc plugin.

Kind regards Christopher

Update Day1

I added tech.NfcV to the Import List

```
import android.nfc.tech.NfcV;
```

Changed the execute function as suggested

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    Log.d(TAG, "execute " + action);

    if (!getNfcStatus().equals(STATUS_NFC_OK)) {
        callbackContext.error(getNfcStatus());
        return true; // short circuit
    }

    createPendingIntent();


    if (action.equals(REGISTER_DEFAULT_TAG)) {
        addTechList(new String[]{NfcV.class.getName()});  //changed this form Mifare to NfcV
        registerDefaultTag(callbackContext);


    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(INIT)) {
        init(callbackContext);

    } else {
        // invalid action
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Problem seems to be that I get Invalid action returned at the moment so something is wrong here

I changed the registerDefault function to

```
private void registerDefaultTag(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
addTechFilter();
callbackContext.success();
}
```

And i changed the Parse Message function to

```
void parseMessage() {
    cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "parseMessage " + getIntent());
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "action " + action);
            if (action == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED) || action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)){

             Tag tagFromIntent  = (Tag)intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
             NfcV mfc = NfcV.get(tagFromIntent);
             fireTagEvent(tag);

            }

            /*if (action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)) {
                Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
                fireNdefEvent(NDEF_MIME, ndef, messages);

            } else if (action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)) {
                for (String tagTech : tag.getTechList()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, tagTech);
                    if (tagTech.equals(NdefFormatable.class.getName())) {
                        fireNdefFormatableEvent(tag);
                    } else if (tagTech.equals(Ndef.class.getName())) { //
                        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
                        fireNdefEvent(NDEF, ndef, messages);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)) {
                fireTagEvent(tag);
            }*/

            setIntent(new Intent());
        }
    });
}
```

So currently i get the error invalid action as soon as i click on  start Listening and calling the Taglisteners in Javascript atm I use all 4 different Listeners to see if any work. It seems that I need to write a new fireEvent function specific for NfcV since the existing ones arent working

Update 2

I have managed to compile the plugin and deploy the app but nothing is happening i am not getting a Tag object back

The parse Message Function

```
void parseMessage() {
    cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "parseMessage " + getIntent());
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.d(TAG, "action " + action);
            if (action == null) {
                return;
            }
        if (action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED) || action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)){
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                    if(tag != null){
                      byte[] id = tag.getId();
                      // set up read command buffer
                      byte blockNo = 0; // block address
                      byte[] readCmd = new byte[3 + id.length];
                      readCmd[0] = 0x20; // set "address" flag (only send command to this tag)
                      readCmd[1] = 0x20; // ISO 15693 Single Block Read command byte
                      
                      System.arraycopy(id, 0, readCmd, 2, id.length); // copy ID
                      readCmd[2 + id.length] = blockNo; // 1 byte payload: block address

                      NfcV tech = NfcV.get(tag);
                      if (tech != null) {
                        // send read command
                        try {
                          tech.connect();
                          byte[] data = tech.transceive(readCmd); 
                          fireTagEvent(data);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                          try {
                            tech.close();
                          } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }

            setIntent(new Intent());
        }
    

    }
 });
}
```

My fireTagEvent

```
private void fireTagEvent(byte[] data) {

    String s2 = new String(data);
    String command = MessageFormat.format(javaScriptEventTemplate, TAG_DEFAULT, s2);
    Log.v(TAG, s2);
    this.webView.sendJavascript(s2);

}
```

The execute function

```
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    Log.d(TAG, "execute " + action);

    if (!getNfcStatus().equals(STATUS_NFC_OK)) {
        callbackContext.error(getNfcStatus());
        return true; // short circuit
    }

    createPendingIntent();


    if (action.equals(REGISTER_DEFAULT_TAG)) {
        addTechList(new String[]{NfcV.class.getName()});
        registerDefaultTag(callbackContext);


    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(INIT)) {
        init(callbackContext);

    } else {
        // invalid action
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thats pretty much it the app starts the "addTagDiscoveredListener" is registered but im not getting any Object back so either the nfcv tag is not read or i just dont get anything back not really sure...

Comment: Hi, I'll take some time this week end to improve my answer. Have you tried importing the app in android studio and setting breakpoints to see if the tag is seen? (and is it seen with the original plugin... I think mine was but I could only get the ID)

Comment: the original plugin is reading the tag fine i am getting the id and the type of  the tag, the problem is i need the byte information stored on the tag. No i have not i am working with visual studio, and telerik appbuilder for hybrid developement, didnt really try to set breakpoints did once but nothing was happening not really familiar with that type of debugging i must admit -.- . Thank you very much really appreciate it

Comment: hey quickfix u got some time to elaborate your approach more i tried for a while without success

Comment: @QuickFix id love if you find some time to explain your customised solution more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I finally managed to get it working

In the Phonegap-nfc.js I added an eventlistener for the NFCV tag

```
addNfcVListener: function (callback, win, fail) {
        document.addEventListener("nfcv", callback, false);
        cordova.exec(win, fail, "NfcPlugin", "registerNfcV", []);
    },
```

The matching Execute function looks like this

```
@Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        Log.d(TAG, "execute " + action);

        if (!getNfcStatus().equals(STATUS_NFC_OK)) {
            callbackContext.error(getNfcStatus());
            return true; // short circuit
        }

        createPendingIntent();


         if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(REGISTER_NFCV)) {
          registerNfcV(callbackContext);

        }else {
            // invalid action
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Here is where the Tag gets added to the techlist

```
private void registerNfcV(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
      addTechList(new String[]{NfcV.class.getName()});
      callbackContext.success();
  }
```

Here the Tag gets parsed and fires an event

```
void parseMessage() {
        cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "parseMessage " + getIntent());
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String action = intent.getAction();


                Log.d(TAG, "action " + action);
                if (action == null) {
                    return;
                }


                if (action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED) || action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)){
                     NfcvData ma;

                     Tag tagFromIntent  = (Tag)intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
                     Parcelable[] messages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra((NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES));
                     NfcV mfc = NfcV.get(tagFromIntent);
                     Tag tag = mfc.getTag();
                     fireNfcVReadEvent(NFCV, mfc, messages);

                }

                setIntent(new Intent());
            }
        });
    }
```

Then this event is called

```
private void fireNfcVReadEvent(String type, NfcV nfcv, Parcelable[] messages) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = buildNfcVReadJSON(nfcv, messages);
        String tag = jsonObject.toString();

        String command = MessageFormat.format(javaScriptEventTemplate, type, tag);
        Log.v(TAG, command);
        this.webView.sendJavascript(command);

    }
```

Which sends the Taginformation back to my Javascript

Comment: Thanks, stackg91 for this. Could you please share your code for the function buildNfcVReadJSON as it is not included in your post.

Answer (score 3):

I used the Chariotsolution plugin as a start to build my own nfc reading plugin. I think it would save you much time if you don't start from scratch.

There are many things you can remove because the original plugin only deals with NDEF tags, but removing lines is faster than re-inventing the wheel.

It's a bit old in my head, so I'm not sure I can explain everything right...
My nead was to read info in Mifare classic tags, but maybe you can adapt for your needs...
So, if you look at NfcPlugin.java, in the execute function, all I kept was the code for the actions REGISTER_DEFAULT_TAG and INIT.

Updated the code in REGISTER_DEFAULT_TAG to register the listening for mifare classic tag. And modified registerDefaultTag function to call addTechFilter instead of addTagFilter.

So this leaves us with
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray data, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

```
    Log.d(TAG, "execute " + action);

    if (!getNfcStatus().equals(STATUS_NFC_OK)) {
        callbackContext.error(getNfcStatus());
        return true; // short circuit
    }

    createPendingIntent();


    if (action.equals(REGISTER_DEFAULT_TAG)) {
        addTechList(new String[]{MifareClassic.class.getName()});
        registerDefaultTag(callbackContext);


    } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(INIT)) {
        init(callbackContext);

    } else {
        // invalid action
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
private void registerDefaultTag(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    addTechFilter();
    callbackContext.success();
}
```

Now what you need to understand is that once you called from the js the init function, the parseMessage function of the plugin will be called each time the device sees a nfc tag.

So in the parseMessage function I have a test

```
if (action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED) || action.equals(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED))
```

in wich I have all the code to deal with my tag.

In that code can get info from the tag in the intent using something like this :

```
            Tag tagFromIntent  = (Tag)intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            MifareClassic mfc = MifareClassic.get(tagFromIntent);
```

and then depending on your treatment you can call either fireErrorEvent or a fire...Event of your own that would return the data to the javascript using the `webView.sendJavascript` function.

I'm running out of time to detail the js part.

Not sure sure if it will help you or if it's the way you want to go (don't know how the tag you're using is working). Let me know if it helps you and if you need more details.

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your reply, this is definatly better than my approach i am going to try to add the nfcv functionality to the chariot plugin. it would be great if you could give me some more details on the javascript part im gone for the weekend so no rush

Comment: i updated my Questions with the changes you suggested getting invalid Action at the moment maybe you could take a look at it if you got time really appreaciate the help

Comment: the mainproblem seems to be firing the nfc event converting the data to json and then using webView.sendJavascript to send it back cant really get it to work..

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are not sending any data back in you callback, just the cordova SUCCESS.  callbackContext.success(returndatahere); See the cordova plugin spec for supported data types.